# How to delete all revisions of given content type except the current revision?

Tags: 8, nodes

I am having a very large website which have around 400000 nodes of story content type. And these nodes have around 2000000 revisions. How can I delete all the revisions except the current revision so i can reduce the size of my database.

I have tried node [node revison delete](https://www.drupal.org/project/node_revision_delete) module with no success. Page is getting time out.

Answer (score 1):

The time out page is happening cause the modules is not using Drupal [batch operation](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21form.inc/group/batch/8.2.x).

Did you try to use drush command that comes with the [same module](https://www.drupal.org/project/node_revision_delete)? you need to install [Drush Help module](https://www.drupal.org/project/drush_help) to do so. If it didn't work, please post it here so I can provide you with a batch code.

Comment: Yes, I have used with crush command but there is no response of drush command with asked question scenario. Drush was working on my dev setup which have only 30000 revisions.